# select table1 column_names where table1 column_names is in table2 column1 values

Tags: sql, database

Table1 :

| col_1 | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 13 | 14 |

Table2 :

| col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | c |

I want to join table1 with table2 on table1.col_1= table2.col1 and select columns from table1 where table2.col2 values  is equal to table1 columns name. Kindly suggest how to do this in SQL

Comment: You would need to write a Stored procedure that queried these tables and then dynamically created the SQL statement and executed it